# Angular Chrome Extension PDFMerge (Require)

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, localhost, package-managers

I have developed an angular chrome extension WebApp using the following tutorial/link - https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575

The WebApp basically runs on the browser like a normal HTML document without any server/localhost involved.

Everything went well, however once I started to use require() and libraries like PDF-Lib or PDFMerge I have encountered a huge flaw where I would need to have the WebApp running on a server so that it can do these functions.

Is there a way to use require() and PDF Libraries without needing to run the WebApp on a localhost server?

Also, I have an idea but I don't know if it's possible. Is there a way to run a temporary server using typescript INSIDE the browser webapp? The idea is to create a localhost when a certain function in the app needs to run and execute it inside that temporary localhost that was initialized using the typescript code.

Here is a little more detail -

Project Structure:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkujq.png)

I run ng build everytime I do a change in the project so that the changes and assets get put inside the dist folder which the chrome extension depends on.

tsconfig.json:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Kz8.png)